# winjs.xhr invalid request

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to let the user to create his own rss aggregator and it works fine, but my problem is when the user input something is not valid for example numbers, it gives me "req.send(options.data)" , and WINJS function is blocked and i can't modify the request when it is invalid, Thanks.

```
                  for (var vv = 0; vv < urll.length; vv++) {

    var Input = { title: [], des: [], link: [], len: "" };

    WinJS.xhr({ url: urll[vv] }).done

        (function (rss) {

                     var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");

                      Input.len = items.length;
                      for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
                          Input.title[n] = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
                          Input.des[n] = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
                          Input.link[n] = items[n].querySelector("link").textContent;
                          if ((Input.link[n] == null) || (Input.link[n] == "")) {
                              Input.link[n] = items[n].querySelector("guid").textContent;
                          }
                      }


                 });
                 if (vv >= 1 && DataInput[DataInput.length - 1].title.length < 2) { DataInput.length = DataInput.length - 1 }
                 DataInput.push(Input);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using done, try using .then and provide a handler function in case xhr request goes wrong: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700337.aspx